# HttpClient.SendAsync is throwing "A task was canceled" issue

Tags: c#, .net, custom-activity

We are making a PUT call to the service layer to update an entity information

HttpClient.SendAsync method is throwing "A task was canceled" issue even though the API call is successfully made to the backend service layer. I could see the logs from service layer.

Initially I thought it could be related to timeout, so I increased the timeout from 10 seconds to 30 seconds, still the program is waiting for 30 seconds and gets timed out with the error "A task was canceled". But the api call was successfully completed in Service Layer within even 5 seconds

Please find below my code

```
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
        string uuid = UUID.Get(context);

        Console.WriteLine(uuid + ": Http Api Call - STARTED");

        string endPoint = EndPoint.Get(context);
        string contentType = ContentType.Get(context);
        string acceptFormat = AcceptFormat.Get(context);
        HttpMethod httpMethod = HttpApiMethod.Get(context);
        string clientCertificatePath = ClientCertificatePath.Get(context);
        string clientCertificatePassword = ClientCertificatePassword.Get(context);
        double httpTimeOut = HttpTimeout.Get(context);
        Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders = RequestHeaders.Get(context);
        Dictionary<string, string> pathParams = PathParams.Get(context);
        Dictionary<string, string> queryParams = QueryParams.Get(context);
        string requestBody = RequestBody.Get(context);


        WebRequestHandler webRequestHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
        webRequestHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer = 1;

        if (clientCertificatePath != null && clientCertificatePath.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = null;
            if (clientCertificatePassword != null && clientCertificatePassword.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(clientCertificatePath.Trim(),
                    clientCertificatePassword.Trim());
            }
            else
            {
                x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(clientCertificatePath.Trim());
            }
            webRequestHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(x509Certificate2);
        }

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(webRequestHandler)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(httpTimeOut)
        };

        if (acceptFormat != null)
        {
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", acceptFormat);
        }

        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = InvokeApiSync(httpClient, endPoint,
                                     httpMethod, contentType,
                                     requestHeaders, pathParams,
                                     queryParams, requestBody,
                                     uuid
                                     );

        HttpResponseMessageObject.Set(context, httpResponseMessage);
        ResponseBody.Set(context, httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        StatusCode.Set(context, (int)httpResponseMessage.StatusCode);

        Console.WriteLine(uuid + ": Http Api Call - ENDED");
    }

    private HttpResponseMessage InvokeApiSync(HttpClient httpClient,
                            string endPoint,
                            HttpMethod httpMethod,
                            string contentType,
                            Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders,
                            Dictionary<string, string> pathParams,
                            Dictionary<string, string> queryParams,
                            string requestBody,
                            string uuid)
    {
        if (pathParams != null)
        {
            ICollection<string> keys = pathParams.Keys;
            if (keys.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (string key in keys)
                {
                    endPoint = endPoint.Replace(":" + key, pathParams[key]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (queryParams != null)
        {
            List<string> keys = new List<string>(queryParams.Keys);
            if (keys.Count > 0)
            {
                endPoint = string.Concat(endPoint, "?", keys[0], "=", queryParams[keys[0]]);
                for (int index = 1; index < keys.Count; index++)
                {
                    endPoint = string.Concat(endPoint, "&", keys[index], "=", queryParams[keys[index]]);
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, endPoint);
            if (requestHeaders != null)
            {
                foreach (string key in requestHeaders.Keys)
                {
                    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(key, requestHeaders[key]);
                }
            }

            if (httpMethod.Equals(HttpMethod.Put) || httpMethod.Equals(HttpMethod.Post))
            {
                StringContent reqContent = null;
                if (requestBody != null)
                {
                    reqContent = new StringContent(requestBody);
                }
                else
                {
                    reqContent = new StringContent("");
                }

                reqContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
                httpRequestMessage.Content = reqContent;
            }

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;

            return httpResponseMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(uuid + " : HttpApi Error Has Occurred");
            Console.WriteLine(uuid + " : " + exception.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(uuid + " : " + exception.StackTrace);
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.!

Comment: Any time you use `Task.Result` you're going to get weird issues - don't do that. Use `await`/`async` properly.

Comment: @DavidG, 

I tried the following as well. Again getting the same issue.

`Task<HttpResponseMessage> taskHttpResp = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
taskHttpResp.Wait();
HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = taskHttpResp.Result;`

Now how do you suggest to get the HttpResponseMessage object after wait() method is completed.

Comment: It sounds like you really need to understand how await/async works, I strongly suggest you go and read up about it. You need `HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);`